# surface energy versus surface tension and contact angles

Tags: surface-chemistry

I am hoping to measure the surface tension between two fluids (salt water and isopropyl alcohol), by measuring the appropriate contact angles, and applying Young's equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting#Simplification_to_planar_geometry.2C_Young.27s_relation

As far as I can tell, the surface energy and surface tension are interchangable, however I thought that I should ask people that know better than I do, just to make sure.

Comment: Nope, both are very different things.

Comment: So, would the above measurement, together with a capillary measurement suffice to calculate the surface tension?

Comment: Surface energy has dimension J/m^2, surface tension has dimension N/m. Their relation is the famous high school formula Work = Force . distance. A liquid with surface tension e.g. $\pu{70 mN/m}$ has surface energy $\pu{70 mJ/m^2}$

Comment: Interfacial tension between two liquids implies that they are immiscible. I don't think you will get a distinct interface between isopropanol and an aqueous salt solution.

Comment: @James Gaidis I generally agree, but I had suspician isopropanol can be salted out, similarly as some other alkohols are. This [amateur youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEFhMfaT-vg) seems confirming the idea, resulting in 2 clearly distinguished phases..

Comment: @Poutnik Yes! That is exactly the idea! I am studying the interface waves on a two-fluid (liquid) system, and I would like to minimize the surface tension between the two fluids. Currently, I am using pure water and propylene carbonate, but the interface has a tendancy to create very tiny bubbles. 
I am hoping that a dynamic equillibrium between the alcohol and the water prevents this problem. As well, propylene carbonate is a pain to work with, since most plastics seem to fall apart when exposed to it.
paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jctb.447

Comment: @Poutnik
Regarding the above example: I am tempted to say that the two quantities are the same, since the dimensions are the same, and they are related to very similar phenomena. Would you expect a capillary measurement to produce different results than the aforementioned Young equation?

Comment: Energy and torque have the same dimension as well, but they are not the same. The partial derivative of Gibb energy per surface area is surface energy, not surface tension.

Comment: @Poutnik
I see... (Good example with torque and energy by the way!) 

But, what do you mean by saying that a liquid with surface tension 70 mN/m has a surface energy of 70 mN/m?

Comment: @user109527 Rather, what do *you* mean by that ? :-). I have written "A liquid with surface tension e.g. 70 mN/m has surface energy 70 mJ/m2". There are scenarios where one is interested in the force, and other scenarios, where one is interested in the energy. It makes more sense, if we leave simple linear and rectangular scenarios for general surfaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112862/discussion-between-poutnik-and-user109527).